# Fetch API post XML request error

Tags: javascript, soap, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I am failing to do a `fetch` POST request. It returns a `400 bad request` error

```
fetch('http://192.168.1.6:49152/ctl/RenderingControl', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "SOAPAction": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1#GetVolume",
        "content-type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
        },
    body: '<?xml version="1.0"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> <s:Body><u:GetVolume xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID><Channel>Master</Channel></u:GetVolume></s:Body></s:Envelope>'
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.text());
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Request failed', error);
    });
```

However this curl request works

```
echo '
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
 <s:Body>
  <u:GetVolume xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1">
   <InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
   <Channel>Master</Channel>
  </u:GetVolume>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
' | curl -v -d @- \
 -H 'SOAPAction: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1#GetVolume"' \
 -H 'content-type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"' \
 http://192.168.1.6:49152/ctl/RenderingControl
```

So I know that the body and header content are correct. But where am I doing wrong with the `fetch` request?

Comment: Unless the frontend JavaScript code you’re making the request with runs on the `http://192.168.1.6:49152` server, it’s a cross-origin request, & so because of that, your browser automatically on its own is sending a CORS preflight OPTIONS request before trying the POST request in your code. And the reason your browser sends that preflight OPTIONS is because your request adds the 'SOAPAction' and `content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' headers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests So is that OPTIONS the request causing the 400 response?

Comment: I do not control the server. I added `USER-AGENT = "UPnP/1.0, UPNPClient/0.0.1"`. It still returns 400 error. I also tried with `mode: 'no-cors'`. Not working.

Comment: You need to contact whoever controls the server and work with them to get it CORS-enabled. Otherwise you won’t be able to browsers to allow your frontend JavaScript code to access responses from it directly. If you can’t manage to get the server CORS-enabled, then your only other option is to make the requests to it from your backend code instead.

Comment: If I am to use [this upnp plugin](https://github.com/thibauts/node-upnp-device-client) in the node console, it works just fine. But not through web or a tabris js app in the mobile.

Comment: If somebody looking for an answer - https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-js/issues/1507