# Tabris JS fetch api handle preflight requests

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, fetch-api, tabris, tabris-js

I have a UPNP MPD server running on a Raspberry Pi connected to my home network.

I am trying to control it through the Tabris app.

```
fetch('http://192.168.1.6:49152/ctl/RenderingControl', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "SOAPAction": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1#GetVolume",
        "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    },
    body: '<?xml version="1.0"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> <s:Body><u:GetVolume xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID><Channel>Master</Channel></u:GetVolume></s:Body></s:Envelope>'
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.text());
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Request failed', error);
    });
```

This code return a `400 bad request` error. However, running a curl request does work

```
echo '
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
 <s:Body>
  <u:GetVolume xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1">
   <InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
   <Channel>Master</Channel>
  </u:GetVolume>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
' | curl -v -d @- \
 -H 'SOAPAction: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1#GetVolume"' \
 -H 'content-type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"' \
 http://192.168.1.6:49152/ctl/RenderingControl
```

I think it is an issue with [preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) but not sure how to correct this.

What exactly is the way to deal with such API requests? Where in the code is the trouble?

Comment: @sideshowbarker This specifically concerns running the code on Tabris JS

Comment: Then you can instead either update https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593491/fetch-api-post-xml-request-error to make it specific to Tabris JS — and then delete this question — or else just delete that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593491/fetch-api-post-xml-request-error question. There’s no value in having two questions here that are describing exactly the same problem.

Comment: Please understand development has paused. But it matters, one specifies usage over web browser and the other concerning Pi and Tabris mobile app. I can't seem to find a solution to either.

Comment: If somebody looking for an answer - https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-js/issues/1507